# Reinstalling Mac OS 10.5

Tags: macos, mac, osx-leopard

I need to install OS X on a machine that has an older apple operating system on it. When trying to install OS 10.5, the installation software finds all the stuff on the disk and complains it hasn't got enough space to complete its job.

I would like to delete everything on the disk and do a complete new install. What do I do wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the screen where you choose the target disk, there is an options button which popups the following dialog.

[image]

Here you are able to choose "Erase and Install".

See the following url:
http://mac.elated.com/2008/04/24/leopard-review-part-1-the-upgrade-process/

Answer (score 0):

Installation procedure has an option for doing a clean install of Leopard.

Alternatively, you can use Disk Utility, available from the install app, to perform any operation on you hard drive, including erasing and formatting.

Comment: Go to disk utility, like mouviciel said. There, erase the drive choosing HFS extended (with journaling), or something like this.